# How to group an ArrayList using RxJava2 based on some attribute?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a class `Person` which has `isChild` attribute along with other attributes

```
class Person {
  boolean isChild;
  //Other attributes.
}
```

Now I have a method with takes a list of `Person` as input. My output should also return a list, but the list should have all the `Person` objects first for whom `isChild` is true, followed by other Person objects. In java, I can do it in the following way.

```
public List<Person> returnListWithChildFirst(@NonNull List<Person> personList) {

    List<Person> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Person> nonChildList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Person person : personList) {
      if (person.isChild) {
        childList.add(person);
      } else {
        nonChildList.add(person);
      }
    }

    childList.addAll(nonChildList);
    return childList;
  }
```

What is the best way to do this in RxJava2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
Observable.fromIterable(personList).sorted( (p1, p2) -> Boolean.compare(!p1.isChild(),!p2.isChild())).toList().blockingGet();
```

Or with java 8

```
personList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::isChild).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using the `sorted` operator:

```
public class RxJavaOrder {
    static class Person {
        public Person(boolean isChild, String name) {
            this.isChild = isChild;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isChild;
        public String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "isChild=" + isChild +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person(true, "Tom"));
        personList.add(new Person(false, "Alie"));
        personList.add(new Person(false, "Ele"));
        personList.add(new Person(true, "Dale"));
        personList.add(new Person(false, "Cherry"));
        Observable.fromIterable(personList)
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> Boolean.compare(o2.isChild, o1.isChild))
                .toList()
                .subscribe(people -> {
                    people.forEach(System.out::println);
                });
    }
}
```